# Porting nullable GUIDs from C# to Java

Tags: c#, java, guid, nullable

I am porting some C# code to the Android platform. The code makes heavy use of nullable GUIDs. I understand they don't exist in Java, so what would be the best way to implement this feature? I am thinking of just using an "empty" GUID (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000) to represent a null value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`java.util.UUID`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) is a class in Java, which means a reference to this type can have the value `null`. The C# type that can't be represented in Java is a *non*-nullable UUID.